# Создание виртуальной среды на termux

Tags: python, termux

При попытке создать виртуальную среду, выдало следующее:

```
$ python -m venv ll_env
Error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:
'lib' -> '/storage/emulated/0/learning_log/ll_env/lib64'
```

> [image: Скриншот терминала]

В чём проблема, и как это исправить?

Comment: Делать это в домашней папке termux, а не на внешней памяти

Comment: andreymal,  важно чтоб это происходило во внешней памяти

Comment: Это невозможно, внешняя память не поддерживает символьные ссылки

Answer (score 1):

Все просто! Надо вместо Python указать путь к нему, добавить ключ -m, обьявить о создании виртуальной среды Python(venv), написать название среды. И все работает!

P.S. Это надо делать только в дериктории ~. В остальных дериктория это не работает.

`/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3 -m venv ll_env`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]